# CS5.5 Watch variables in "Variables" window

Tags: flash, debugging, adobe, debug-symbols, flash-cs5.5

This is more of a lazy programmer question, but is there any way to change how variables are listed in the "Variables" window for debugging? Specifically, it neatly lists all local variables for whatever block is currently executing, but in order to inspect non-local variables I have to dive down a cumbersome number of drop down tabs (this->that->SomeOtherLayer->ThatObject->AChild->ThatThingYouWantedToSee). This is particularly painful as a change to a new block minimizes the drop-downs and so I am forced to constantly recheck my variables.

I am aware of the power of trace statements, and while they can help keep tabs on execution, if there is a method of somehow "tagging" specific variables to watch in a similar fashion to the top-level listed local variables, I would be one happy camper.

Answer (score 1):

Use Flash Builder, which allows for watch expressions.  Also, most of the time it will sort of remember what variable you were last looking at in a Class, and the next time it goes through that code it will open straight to that variable (not guaranteed, but most of the time).